# How the superoperator is related with jump operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator, open-quantum-systems

Suppose I have the following Lindblad master equation:
$$
\frac{d\rho}{dt}=\mathcal{L}[\rho]=-\frac{1}{2}\left(L^\dagger L \rho+\rho L^\dagger L-2L\rho L^\dagger\right)
$$
where $\rho$ is a single-spin density matrix (i.e., a 2$\times$2 matrix), and $L$ is the 2$\times$2 jump operator, and $\mathcal{L}$ is a 4$\times$4 superoperator. Now, if I have a two-spin system represented by $\rho'$ (i.e., now $\rho'$ is a 4$\times$4 density matrix) such that
$$
\frac{d\rho'}{dt}=\mathcal{L}'[\rho']=-\frac{1}{2}\left(L'^\dagger L' \rho'+\rho' L'^\dagger L'-2L'\rho' L'^\dagger\right)
$$
where the jump operator still acts on the first spin (i.e., I have $L'=L\otimes \mathbb{I}$). How would then the superoperator $\mathcal{L}'$ is related to $\mathcal{L}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The superator $\mathcal L'$ would be defined on untangled states $\rho' = \rho_1 \otimes \rho_2$ by :
$$\mathcal L'[\rho_1 \otimes \rho_2] = \mathcal L[\rho_1]\otimes \rho_2$$
and extend by linearity to a general density matrix $\rho'$.