# How to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the superoperator from those of the jump operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, density-operator, eigenvalue, open-quantum-systems

Suppose I have the following Lindblad master equation:
$$
\frac{d\rho}{dt}=\mathcal{L}[\rho]=-\frac{1}{2}\left(L^\dagger L\rho+\rho L^\dagger L-2L\rho L^\dagger\right)
$$
where $L$ is the jump operator, and $\mathcal{L}$ is the superoperator. Now if $|r_i\rangle$ and $\langle l_i|$ are the right and left eigenvectors of $L$ with the respective eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_i^*$, then can I write the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the superoperator $\mathcal{L}$ using $|r_i\rangle$, $\langle l_i|$, $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_i^*$?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/644392/2451

Comment: Qmechanic: No, it is not related to that one. There the question was about the form of the superoperator. Here I am interested in the eigenvectors and eigenvalues. These two are different questions.